# How to validate email with jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

In some cases jQuery [Validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) is not perfect for email validation.
"abc@test.c"(Single letter suffix) and "중국어@test.com"(Non alpha-numeric) get passed as valid email addresses.

How can I filter these two invalid email addresses using jQuery Validate plugin?

Comment: use `remote: ` rule for custom validation.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, please explain how [`remote:`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options) has anything to do with this.

Comment: `remote: ` rule can define external script to implement customized logic. Therefore, you can handle exceptional cases that are not covered by default validation.

Answer (score 0):

[As per the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage), you'll need to construct your own custom method.

> Add a custom validation method. It must consist of a name (must be a
>   legal javascript identifier), a javascript based function and a
>   default string message.
>
> **Arguments:**
>
> **name;** String   The name of the method, used to identify and referencing it, must be a valid javascript identifier
>
> **method;** Callback   The actual method implementation, returning true if an element is valid. First argument: Current value. Second
>   argument: Validated element. Third argument: Parameters.
>
> **message (Optional);** String, Function   The default message to display for this method. Can be a function created by
>   jQuery.validator.format(value). When undefined, an already existing
>   message is used (handy for localization), otherwise the field-specific
>   messages have to be defined.

---

The following is a custom `method` that I named `newemail`.  Right now, it's just using the default function for "email" validation.  Simply edit the regex within this function to suit your particular needs.

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("newemail", function(value, element) {
            // contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
            return this.optional(element) || /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i.test(value); 
}, "Please enter a valid email address");
```

Then use it inside `.validate()` just like you would use any other rule.

```js
rules: {
    InputName: {
        required: true,
        newemail: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using `remote:`:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        femail: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: "lib/ajax/checkEmail.php"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        femail: {
            required: 'Please input email',
            email: 'Please input valid email',
            remote: 'This email is duplicated/invalid, please re-input an email'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

In `checkEmail.php`, it implements extra logic to validate special cases, then at least echo either `true` or `false` in return.

Hope it helps.